# WordPress category unlisted when updating

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got an issue regarding categories I have never seen before.
I am able create a new category, and then everything is OK, the category is listed.

When updating a category in the WordPress admin, the category becomes unlisted. At postboxes, at the category admin page and with `get_categories()` as well.

However, the category is still viewable on the frontend, and I can access the category edit page when putting the right term ID in the URL (for example, I put `43` as ID in the browser omnibar.

`wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=category&tag_ID=43&post_type=post&wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit-tags.php%3Ftaxonomy%3Dcategory`

I have searched the database but can't find anything. I searched the theme and can't find anything. I ran the `WP_ALLOW_REPAIR` database repair process, but no luck. The tool even says no repair was needed at all.

The site is running a theme from SMThemes and runs dual language with the WPML plugin.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The categories disappearing was caused by a bug in WPML version `2.7.1`.

More information: [[Resolved] Categories disappear after WPML activated](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/categories-disappear-after-wpml-activated/)

The troubleshooting options did not work for me, however. I decided to outcomment the `add_filter` `terms_clauses` in the `sitepress.class.php` file.